# How can I add a package to the default installation of Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, system-installation, debian-installer, ubiquity

I want to add the `xclip` package as default package in Ubuntu. When I install Linux then `xclip` package should also be installed with it. How can I do it?

Comment: Which distribution?

Comment: Assuming you are not asking for xclip to be included in Debian/RedHat/SuSE/Ubuntu etc., you would need to change the local copy of the ISO you downloaded for your distributions. That normally only pays off if you are going to install many times (e.g. when setting up a test) environment from scratch. If that is not the case suggest you make script that you run after the normal install doing all the repetitive things you want to have done to a new installation including installing xclip

Comment: Ubuntu. And I want to run the script at the time of installation of kernel.

Comment: Ubuntu has two installers (see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Installer/Development for background); which one are you trying to modify?